# not working threads in sfml

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, sfml

Hi for beginning I want to say that I'm new in this stuff so sorry for this basic question.

```
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void func()
{
    // this function is started when thread.launch() is called

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << "I'm thread number one" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    // create a thread with func() as entry point
    sf::Thread thread(&func);

    // run it
    thread.launch();

    // the main thread continues to run...

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << "I'm the main thread" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

this is code from sfml offical site and it should be printing:

> I'm thread number one
>
> I'm the main thread
>
> I'm the main thread
>
> I'm thread number one
>
> I'm thread number one

etc but console print first 10x times "I'm thread number one" and the the second one and i have no idea why. I used this tutorial to install sfml https://youtu.be/axIgxBQVBg0 .

Comment: You have no control over threads, when they actually start to run, and for how long. Try increasing the number of time the output is written, and you should see *blocks* of output from each thread mixing (the output won't be coming one from each without some synchronization).

Comment: The operating system decides when to schedule threads. If you want predictable multi-threaded behavior, you need synchronization primitives. The tutorial I assume you're following has an example with a mutex if you keep reading. Also, SFML explicitly recommends using `std::thread` over `sf::Thread`

Answer (score 0):

The example from SFML's website is an example of *potential* output. If you notice the output given in that example seems a little unpredictable that is because it is. You are extremely unlikely to reproduce it. As [noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51507890/not-working-threads-in-sfml#comment89984884_51507890) you won't have explicit control over the threads without further synchronization.